# Expect Script to Throw a Message if the SSH Fails

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scripting, expect

I am trying to run a Script to SSH to multiple Servers to run Few Commands and show results. I managed to write a Script to Skip and go to next server if SSH Fails. But i couldnt make it throw a Message or Comment if the SSH Fails. Someone , please help. Below is my Script.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1
set hostlist [open ./ddlicall.txt]
set ipaddrs [read $hostlist]

foreach line [split $ipaddrs \n] {

    spawn ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o LogLevel=quiet sysadmin@$line
    expect {
        "assword:"
        {
            send "MY-PASSWORD\r"
            expect {
                "sysadmin@"
                {
                    send "elicense license-server show\r"
                    expect "sysadmin@"
                    send "exit\r"
                }

                "assword:" {
                    send \x03
                    puts "\nIncorrect Password\n"
                    expect eof
                }
            }
        }
    
        "send:"
        {
            puts "\nSSH Issue\n"
            # expect eof
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should look into using keys to avoid the password and expect script completly, or use sshpass.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect all you need to do is change `"send:"` to `eof`. If ssh fails, then the spawned process exits and you can expect to see the eof pattern.

Another small issue I see: `read` will read the whole file, including the trailing newline at the end of the file. Then `[split $ipaddrs \n]` will create a list with an empty string as the last element. That empty `$line` value will cause an error for the last iteration of the loop.

To fix that, there are 2 choices:

1. `set ipaddrs [read -nonewline $hostlist]` or
2. `foreach line [split [string trim $ipaddrs] \n] {`